# Why keep getting the same error in PyCharm 'error running Unknown error'?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, gpu

I'm working on `PyCharm,` but I keep facing the same problem `error running Unknown error` from time to time.
I already updated it to the latest version. Moreover, I got the system crash in the middle of the training, and it gets stuck on `Waiting for process detach`. Also, when I close it and rerunning it, it shows `Could not load dynamic library`.

**Update**:
Adding to the problem above, sometimes,  I can not see any output on the console. I have reinstalled it, but without any success.

**New Update**
After updating the PyCharm from `2021.1.1` to `2021.1.2`, it seems that the problem has been solved.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Isn't the error caused by the code you are running that is not included in the question?

Comment: The code runs and does not cause any problem but the problem is that `PyCharm` crashes.

Comment: I get the same error.  It occasionally will not show the output and, unless I restart PyCharm, won't run the script.  The only thing odd about my script is that I include some functions from another py file.  Other wise it's run of the mill code.

Comment: In my case, the code was running perfectly, but lately, it starts to show these problems.